# Sorting Array in O(n) run time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

If you do not have any constraints regarding memory is there any algorithm to sort a given array with duplicates in O(n) ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: What about Spaghetti-sort? Though it does requires a non-trivial computing device.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends. If you can bound your input in some way with both a lower and upper bound (and maximum precision/value length), then you can use a [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) which is `O(n)`. Similarly, [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) can have `O(n)` complexity in the best case, but degrades to `O(n^2)` for bad inputs.

In general, however, if you cannot bound your input and need to use a comparison based sort, it can be proven that `O(n log n)` is optimal.

When sorting fixed precision integers or floating point numbers (normally up to 64-bits), the values are effectively bounded, and radix sort is possible.

Even if the maximum bit-length of the values is bounded, the longer the bit-length, the larger the constant. In effect, if there are n-values to sort, and each value can have a length or precision up to m bits, the algorithmic complexity is O(nm).

Comment: Yes and how do you express _m_ in terms of _n_? Well _m_ is in O(log _n_), right? So you cannot really get better than O(_n_ log _n_) after all.

Comment: m is not necessarily in terms of n. I can have 1 million 8-bit integers to sort. It just means that there are repeats.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. 
If you do not have any limitations regarding space complexity then you can sort the array with o(n) time complexity.

- Suppose you have an array of k (let k =10) elements.
- And (Let) your array is : N[2,6,4,4,1,1,9,5,2,2]
- Now, as our consideration we do not have any limitations regarding
  space.
- Assume that we have a two dimensional array (temp_number[i][j]) of
  size p (theoretically, consider p is infinite) such that on index i
  contains some flag and index j contains a link list.

Now, Fill the temp_number[ ][ ] such that every element of array N is put in the index of temp_number[ ][ ] and make flag=1 **otherwise** keep flag=0.

```
temp_number[0][1] = [1][1->1->null]
 temp_number[1][1] = [1][2->2->2->null]
 temp_number[2][1] = [0][3->null]
 temp_number[3][1] = [1][4->4->null]
 temp_number[4][1] = [1][5->null]
temp_number[5][1] = [1][6->null]
temp_number[6][1] = [0][null]
temp_number[7][1] = [0][null]
temp_number[8][1] = [1][9->null] & so on...
```

- Now, you can get all the elements who have **flag=1** in a **single loop**.
- Note, here in this way, we are not doing like

  if(number1 > number2) { //sorting logic... }

  so, here you can get the complexity 0(n) because **only one loop** is there.